# Comment filter design for closed topics

Tags: parse-platform

In my app, multiple people can chat on a topic. However once the topic has been closed by its owner, chat should also be disabled on that topic.

My Tables -

1. ChatComment -  a new comment is stored here as a record - it contains pointer to Topic
2. Topic - details related to topic for eg. body, owner, status - open/closed

I'm using cloud functions to create a new comment made by a person on its owner. So everytime I call the cloud function to write new comment, it first queries 'Topic' class to check if topic is still open or not, if its open itll go forward to create new comment in comment class, or else it will throw error.

My problem is that in realtime so many people chat on the topic so frequently that the first query(that checks if topic is still open) occurs for each comment and adds a delay. It really kills user experience.
Can we write a filter to meet above conditions? Please advice me how to deal with this in any other way if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to fake it, the idea works like this:

For the user making the comment, as soon as they enter a comment show it in the topic as if it was added normally. Then start the async call to your cloud function and update the status based on the result.

You might choose to do nothing with the confirmation, or do something like iOS Messages app that shows a "Delivered" tag.

If the cloud function comes back with an error because the topic was closed, update the message to highlight that it was rejected (strikethrough is appropriate here) and disable the ability to add more comments.

This gives the illusion of speed in a delayed system.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy, it totally makes total sense. I am currently doing it this way but I just thought if there could be a filter mechanism that wouldn't cost me an api call. Because when the topic is not closed, for every comment it will check if topic is closed or not (1 api request) and then save the comment (1 api request). I just want to somehow avoid making the first api request.